# Matplotlib image not displaying in Django template

Tags: django, matplotlib

I have a seaborn barplot image that I would like to display inside a django template.

I have looked at a few solutions and I managed to display the image with HttpResponse. However, the image it displays is just an image. What I want is an image of the plot on a webpage and you can still click the navbar and home button etc.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from io import BytesIO
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
```

In views.py

```
def top_causal(request):
  # code for data manipulation
  f = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
  ax = sns.barplot(data)
  # labels, title etc...

  FigureCanvasAgg(f)
  buf = BytesIO()
  plt.savefig(buf, format='png)
  plt.close(f)

  # this works
  response = HttpResponse(buf.getvalue(), content_type='image/png')
  return response

  # What I want which is to display the image inside a template(does not work)
  buffer = buf.getvalue()
  content_type="image/png"
  graphic = (buffer, content_type)
  rendered = render_to_string('top_causal.html', {'graphic': graphic})
  return HttpResponse(rendered)
```

in top_causal.html

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ graphic|safe }}" alt="Not working.">
```

HttpResponse displays the image as a page.

The response using render_to_string returns this instead of an image inside the webpage. I can still see the navbar.

```
\x06\x1d\x00\x80kT\xb7n]eee\x95\x18\xff\xe1\x87\x1f$I\xf5\xea\xd5\xb3\x19\xcf\xce\xce.\x11\x9b\x9d\x9d-WWW999U\xb8~\xa7N\x9d$\xfd\xf6\x02\xb2\xb0\xb00IR\x9b6mt\xe4\xc8\x91\x12\xb1G\x8e\x1c\x91\xc5b\xb9\xea\xe7\xe1\xda\xb5k\xa7\xf7\xdf\x7f_\xc5\xc5\xc5:|\xf8\xb0V\xadZ\xa5\xe7\x9f\x7f^\xb5j\xd5\xd2\xd4\xa9S\xafx\xee\xdbo\xbf\xad\x81\x03\x07j\xc9\x92%6\xe3\xb9\xb9\xb9\xe5\xba\x9e\xbau\xeb\xcab\xb1h\xc2\x84\t\x9a0aB\xa91M\x9b6-W\xae\xab\xa9W\xaf\x9e\xaaU\xab\xa6\xbd{\xf7\xaaj\xd5\xaa%\xe6]\\\\\xecR\xe7\xb2;\xef\xbcSqqq\x92~{Q\xde\xbb\xef\xbe\xaby\xf3\xe6\xa9\xb8\xb8X\x8b\x16-\xb2k-\x00\x80\xe3b\x07\x1d\x00\x80k\xd4\xb7o_\xa5\xa4\xa4\x94x\x13w||\xbc\xaaT\xa9\xa2\x90\x90\x10\x9b\xf1\xf7\xdf\x7f\xdfz\x8b\xb5$\x9d;wN[\xb7n-\x11W^\x97o\x8do\xd6\xac\x99ul\xc8\x90!JIIQJJ\x8au\xec\xd7 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discarded the idea of using matplotlib and went to use Highcharts https://www.highcharts.com/ instead to plot my graph and display it on the webpage.

The data displayed was done by using Django's ORM and Query API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image to byte array, encode it to base64 and embed it to your template. Here is how you do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--my_template.html-->
<html>
  <div class='section'>
    <div class='flex column plot mt15 mlr15 justify-left align-left'>
      <img src='{{ imuri }}'/>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

```py
from django.template.loader import get_template

def top_causal(request):

    # .......................
    # Get your plot ready ...
    # .......................

    figure = plt.gcf()
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    figure.savefig(buf, format='png', transparent=True, quality=100, dpi=200)
    buf.seek(0)
    imsrc = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
    imuri = 'data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(urllib.parse.quote(imsrc))
    context = { 'plot': imuri}

    # Now embed that to your template
    template = get_template('my_template.html')
    html = template.render(context=context)

    # Your template is ready to go...
```

Comment: Do i still need to add `return render(request, 'top_causal.html', context)` at the end of the function?

Comment: Sure, the rest is what you do when you render an ordinary django template, I just wanted to show the point.

Comment: I've amended the codes to the way yours look but the image still isn't appearing. The warning i got were `WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.` and `QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread` which appears in my command window but the website is still running as per normal. Does this mean I need to restart and run again?

Comment: Well, the problem that you are facing is that matplotlib uses tkinter, which must run on the main thread. So if you plot your image on the main thread or use a multi-processor job libraries such as celery etc., this will work.

Comment: My backend is using Agg. How do I go to the main thread and plot there?

Comment: If you get the warning `QApplication was not created in the main() thread.`, you are effectively not using the agg backend. Potentially that's a topic for a new question, but make sure to have `matplotlib.use("Agg")` on top of the code, before importing pyplot.